# Viewing boot time scheduled tasks?

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

Does windows provide any list to view scheduled tasks that will run on next restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the Sysinternals [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) utility.

Comment: To reduce the clutter to make it easier to use, select the following options (then refresh): *Verify Code Signatures, (Hide Windows Entries), Hide Microsoft and Windows Entries*.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to easily manage startup tasks, and do routine Windows maintenance.  It's a free download.

Also, you can go to Control Panel > Scheduled Tasks to see tasks that run at and after startup.

Answer (score 0):

In the registry, you should be able to find a 'list' of programs that will start up.

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

etc...

A good microsoft support page can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179365) with more details.

Comment: `'list' of programs that will start up` - I'm looking programs starting at OS boot loader.

Comment: Dave wants to view *scheduled tasks*, not autorun programs (of which those two keys comprise a small subset anyway).

Comment: RunOnce and RunOnceEx (which are found in the same essential location) is a location that a lot of programs use to designate a startup on next boot.

@dave, OS boot loader? are you essentially asking about the windows equiv. of lilo or grub? because the OS boot loader is much different than `view scheduled tasks that will run on next restart`